# show $L_p(X)$ is a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space. For simple functions
$$
f(\omega)=
\begin{cases}
x_1, \text{ if } \omega \in A_1,\\
\vdots \\
x_n, \text{ if } \omega \in A_n,\\
\end{cases},
$$
define
$$\|f\|_{L_p(X)} = \left( \sum_j \mu(A_j)\|x_j\|^p \right)^{1/p}$$
provided the $A_j$s are disjoint. In general,
$$\|f\|_{L_p(X)} = \left( \int \|f(\omega)\|^p_X \mathrm d\mu \right)^{1/p}$$
for all $f$ in the closure of simple functions. The completion is denoted by $L_p(X)$. Show that $L_p(X)$ is a Banach space.

I was able to show $\|cf\|_{L_p(X)} = |c|\|f\|_{L_p(X)}$ and $\|f\|_{L_p(X)} = 0 \implies f = 0$. But I do not know how to show the triangle inequality. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The fact that $L^p(X, \mu)$ is a Banach space is a theorem due to Riesz and Fischer. For a proof, you can check the classical book by H. Brezis (Theorem 4.8 if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: @Player1235 It looks like Minowski inequality...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we need to show that

$$\|f\|_{L_p(X)} = \left( \int \|f(\omega)\|^p_X \mathrm d\mu \right)^{1/p}$$

is a norm, particularly the triangle inequality.

The triangle inequality:

$$\|f+g\|_{L_p(X)}^p = \left( \int \|f+g\|^p_X \mathrm d\mu \right)$$
$$\leq\left( \int (\|f\|_X+\|g\|_X)^p \mathrm d\mu \right)^{1/p}$$
$$=\left( \int  (\|f\|_X+\|g\|_X)(\|f\|_X+\|g\|_X)^{p-1} \mathrm d\mu \right)$$
$$=\left( \int  \|f\|_X(\|f\|_X+\|g\|_X)^{p-1} \mathrm d\mu +\int  \|g\|_X(\|f\|_X+\|g\|_X)^{p-1} \mathrm d\mu  \right)$$
$$\leq (\|f\|_{L_p(X)}+\|g\|_{L_p(X)})\|f+g\|_{L_p(X)}^{p-1}$$

Where in the last line we used Hölder, this is the Minowski inequality.